# Using the same URL for multiple nested ember routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a case using Ember where I want to make the top level URL available (ie. localhost:4200/demo), and have all the routes underneath also display the same URL (localhost:4200/demo). So the route file, if possible would look something like:

```
this.route('demo', function() {
  this.route('one', { path: '/' });
  this.route('submit', { path: '/' });
});
```

I understand that `ENV.locationtype` can be set for the whole app, but is there a way to conditionally set this for specific URLs underneath a parent URL?

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you end up hitting major snags like this it is because Ember is implicitly trying to tell you that what you are doing isn't a good idea.

Is there a particular reason that you don't want your sub-routes to affect the URL in any way? Could you get by with random values in the URL if your prime purpose is to obfuscate things?

Ember uses the URL to work out what state things should be in in your app. If you don't want to use the routes at all you wouldn't have to, but then at that point you are dealing with a nested hierarchy of components that you have to switch between yourself. Which would in essence be akin to using React without a router ...

Comment: I agree. Have decided against modifying history_location.js file and going down the path of improving readability and structure of the dynamic components.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ember can manage URLs, or it can be set to not manage them, but it seems like the desired intent is to have it do both in a single environment, which is not logically allowed.

If `none` is declared for `ENV.locationtype`, then Ember's default URL management is turned off. This is an "environment-wide" configuration.

If the Ember Router is being used to map nested routes, and default URL management is in play, then observe that you cannot have the same URL path defined for multiple, sibling, child routes.

A further observation, is that your attempt above is tapping into functionality governed by the [single `index` route](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_index-routes) that is available at every nesting level within the Router map. However, a route cannot have multiple `index` routes. Only the last one defined will be recognized.

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('demo', function() {
    this.route('one', { path: '/' })    // <-- this is over-ridden by "submit"
    this.route('submit', { path: '/' }) // <-- this defines an "index" route for demo
  })
})
```

Comment: I would have thought so too, but according to the docs, ENV.locationtype can be set to none - https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/configuring-ember/specifying-url-type/. So this suggests that EmberRouter that is setting the URL in packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js could be customised and over-ridden at the app level leaving core conventions in place.

Comment: Well I'd like to disturb ember routes as little as possible and still use all the helpers like {{link-to}} with the object dot notation to reference routes. The { path: '/string' } object in the route function is already overriding the default URL structure, so it seems quite doable to make this submit to the parent route. Might have to roll a plugin which adds a { useParent: true } object or similar. Was hoping there might be existing functionality though, or someone who had done something similar.

Comment: @Ezra I've updated the answer with further detail. I hope this helps to clarify.

Comment: Cheers @jacefarm. I'm still on my way through the investigation. Looks like the ember.js core packages/ember-routing/lib/location/history_location.js contains all the functions that manage the paths, but they're all private. So it's looking like I'm going to have to replicate/override them in a custom plugin or some such.